# What does it mean that a sub-class's constructor followed by a base class constructor after a colon?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I would like to know what the code which is followed by a base class constructor does. Here is the code:

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class Person
{
public:
    Person() : name(""), age(0) {}

protected:
    string name;
    int age;
};

class Student : public Person
{
public:
    Student() : Person::Person() {}

private:
    int student_id;
};
```

I know what the code does in class `Person`:

`Person() : name(""), age(0) {}`

But I do not understand what this line does in class `Student`:

`Student() : Person::Person() {}`

So what it the meaning of `Person::Person()` after the colon?

Comment: This should be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Student() : Person::Person() {}` is calling the constructor of the base class `Person` in the [member initialization list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) of the derived `Student` constructor.

Note that `Person::Person()` can be simplified to just `Person()` in that context, as there is no need to fully qualify it using its class type.

`Student() : Person() {}`

You don't *need* to specify a base class constructor in the member initialization list of a derived constructor unless the derived constructor passes input values to the base class constructor.  Which your code does not, so you can optionally omit the base class constructor call entirely.  `Person()` is a [default constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor), which the compiler will call automatically for you.

`Student() {}`

In which case, you can optionally also omit the `Student` constructor entirely, since it doesn't initialize anything else explicitly.